# How to turn on all warnings in GCC while using VS Code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, gcc-warning

Recently i came across a problem written in C where there was some undefined behaviour due to which there was some segmentation error. While other people who helped me debugging it were getting warnings from their compiler which was GCC too. In my case while running that same problem in VS Code it gives no warnings and not even a single error and sadly no output. The execution starts and then closes own its own in the terminal.
I use Windows 11.

I want this kinds of warnings.
[People who helped me got this kind of warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tosUZ.png)

Comment: There is no option to turn on all the warnings in `gcc`. Contrary to the expectations, `-Wall` doesn't do that, but it's a good starting point nevertheless. It enables the most useful (according to somebody) warnings. If not enough, add `-Wextra`.  If still not enough, look at the picture. If you use `clang`, there is such an option: `-Weverything` (you may or may not like it). Note, a program that compiles with no warnings at all, even with all warnings enabled, is not automatically correct in any sense of the word. No warnings is the point where you start *debugging*.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is not required to raise diagnostic messages.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit where do i add -Wextra ?

Comment: "Where do i add this warnings(-Wall and -Wextra etc)" This is my main question? @n.m.willseey'allonReddit

Comment: You add these command-line parameters to the command line where you invoke gcc. Now if you have some kind of an IDE to invoke gcc for you, there should be some kind of menu or a property page or a json file or who knows what else where you add command line arguments; it depends on your specific IDE. For VSCode it is probably tasks.json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try adding `-Wall -Wextra` when you compile, like this:

`gcc main.c -o executable.exe -Wall -Wextra`

Those options tell compiler to be more strict and show you more warnings. You can see what exactly they do on this [page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options)

Comment: will adding this warning sets in my task.json file do any help? or everytime I write a code i'll have to call the gcc command in the terminal

I highly appreciate your help!! Thanks

Comment: I don't use VS Code so I don't know what task.json is, but you can automate building process by putting command in batch script (.bat file) and then running the script.
I hope that helps.

Comment: _"...the latest version of GCC."_ -- This doesn't seem relevant. The most recent version of GCC 8, 9, 10, 11, 12? A system wide installation may not be "the latest version" and it is probably a bad idea to try to update this to the most recent version. Not sure why you used `main.cpp` instead of `main.c`.

Comment: @adabsurdum sorry I will corrected that. I just have a habit.

Comment: @adabsurdum Why would it be a bad idea to update to the latest version?

Comment: The system relies on libraries built from the system wide installation, and changing that installation can lead to incompatibilities when linking against libraries compiled by the older compiler. You can of course install multiple versions side-by-side. But, more to the point, what is the virtue of installing a newer compiler for warnings (unless your present compiler is ancient)?

Comment: @adabsurdum Every Linux distribution I've seen lets you install a newer GCC separately, without disturbing the system-wide one, which would indeed be a bad idea. You'll then have e.g. `g++` (the default one) and `g++-12`. So updating is a good idea.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat -- yes, of course it is possible to install multiple versions and I did mention that. The advice to _"be sure that you are running the latest version of GCC"_ is what I took issue with since this did not seem very relevant to the problem and could lead to problems especially for the less experienced (due to potentially borking a system installation, e.g.). Unless a learner is using an ancient compiler, it seems a bit much to suggest they update to the latest GCC (10.5 is more recent than 13.1 to add confusion) before learning how to turn on warnings.